# Combining vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I’m wondering how I can combine vectors in MATLAB in the following way:
I have a vector

```
S= [0.1 0.2 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.5 1 3]
```

And a second vector with same length

```
B= [1 1 4 4 6 7 9 10]
```

Now I would need to have a vector A with as many elements as the potential numbers in B (in this example e.g 10) and this vector should contain the value of S when B’s content equals the index of A. And if there are several potential S values it should contain the mean of those. If there is no value in B that equals th index of A, A should contain Na.

So in this example

```
A= [0.15 NaN NaN 0.2 NaN 0.1 0.5 NaN 1 3]
```

Comment: This sound a lot like an XY problem to me. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through and compute the mean for all indices between 1 and `max(B)`. You can extract the elements of `S` to average using logical indexing (`S(B == k)`). Also, the mean of an empty array (`mean([])`) is always going to yield a `NaN` so that will create `NaN` values automatically for you in the cases where `B` doesn't contain a particular index.

```
A = arrayfun(@(k)mean(S(B == k)), 1:max(B))

%  0.1500   NaN   NaN   0.2000   NaN   0.1000   0.5000  NaN  1.0000  3.0000
```

If we break that down into a for loop it would look something like this

```
for k = 1:max(B)
    % Find elements of B that contain this value of k
    touse = B == k;

    % Grab elements of S that correspond to these entries in B
    svalues = S(touse);

    % Now take the average and store it in our result. 
    % If svalues is empty, then this will be a NaN
    A(k) = mean(svalues);
end
```

If we want this to be more general we would probably want to make the range `min(B):max(B)` rather than `1:max(B)`

```
A = arrayfun(@(k)mean(S(B == k)), min(B):max(B));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!! Can I the same way also calculate back from  A to S?

Comment: @NinaG That isn't possible as there is no unique value of `S` given the value of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) does:

```
A = accumarray(B(:), S(:), [], @mean, NaN).';
```

The third input, `[]`, specifies that the size of the result should be the minimum possible, determined by maximum value of `B`. The fourth input, `@mean`, specifies the function to apply to each group of elements from `S` determined by each value of `B`. The fifth input, `NaN`, is the fill value.